# mustache vs mustache.js, whats the difference?

Tags: mustache

I cant work out the difference between the two, do I need one to make the certain things work better? I am using moustache.js in a rails app and it works fine but... am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically Mustache is implemented in different languages: Ruby, JavaScript, Python, PHP, Perl, Objective-C, Java, .NET, Android, C++, Go, Lua, Scala... mustache.js is the javascript implementation of it.